# Using tcpdump to trace IP of strangers(predators) on omegle

Tags: networking, ip, tcpdump, wireshark, trace

I am using tcpdump to capture packets while being on omegle. However, I have been fairly unsuccessful to get strangers IP. All the IP I see are traced back to either 172.*.*.* which is for google  104.23.*.* for omegle and some servers. Now, commands I've used are
`tcpdump -nn src 192.168.42.152`, which is my src address,
Have also tried
`tcpdump -ttnnvvS` for complete raw output. But in vain. Am I doing it wrong? I remember using wireshark and it was pretty easy with it, but don't happen to have wireshark at the moment.
Also note that, I am not using the IP for any sort of illegal activity nor am I using it to pull a silly prank on anyone.
Wanna help me out a bit here? Are there any other ways except wireshark to do that?
Also, ethernet was my only interface hence no -i eth0.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark captures packets from network interface the same way as tcpdump is, so you won't see different results. You might check this yourself: `tcpdump [...] -w dump_file.pcap`, transfer the resulting file to the other machine that has wireshark and load it there for review.

Comment: Hey I tried `tcpdump -ttnnvvS -w omegle.pcap`, and fired up wireshark on a different distro, and yeah, it showed the same output as tcpdump did. I wonder if it has something to do with me using my phone as a modem for internet. I'm on my pc and there's no wifi module in my pc, and I thought it'd be a good idea to use my phone's left over data to do that.